# Android WiFi Direct (P2P) question about BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm trying to develop a WiFi Direct data transfer app, and [this official help page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#create-application) is my current information source. However, I did not understand this sentence -

```
For the class' constructor, you will use parameters for the WifiP2pManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel, and the activity that this broadcast receiver will be registered in.
```

The *activity* they're talking about is the private member in the below class -

```
/**
* A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important Wi-Fi p2p events.
*/
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   private WifiP2pManager manager;
   private Channel channel;
   private MyWiFiActivity activity; // <-- THIS ONE

   public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
           MyWifiActivity activity) {
       super();
       this.manager = manager;
       this.channel = channel;
       this.activity = activity;
   }
}
```

When I try to implement the class as-it-is, I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol MyWiFiActivity`.

Should I include an import of that type, or does it depend on something else I need to do later on?

Answer (score 0):

The activity they are referring to is created in the [sample project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectActivity.java/) associated with the tutorial. It registers the broadcast receiver and handles lifecycle events among other things. You should change the reference to whatever class you choose to implement the respective callbacks in.